# jaxb nested list elements returns null

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to convert xml to java object using following jaxb code.
When i unmarshall the xml file i get value only for the version attribute in Settings element. Connections value is coming as null.
Please help me find out my mistake(s).WHat more details can i add?
PS:Kindly excuse my beginner level knowledge in java.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Settings version="3" xmlns="urn:Adapter-v3">
    <Connections>
    <Connection name ="Dev" description="DEV">
      <Share version="CS" siteURL="https://example.com" />
    </Connection>    
    <Connection name ="Dev1" description="DEV1">
      <Share version="OM" siteURL="https://example.com" /> 
    </Connection>
</Connections>
</Settings>
```

POJO classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Settings", namespace="urn:Adapter-v3")
public class Settings {

    Connections connections;
    private String version;

    @XmlElement(name="Connections")
    public Connections getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    public void setConnections(Connections connections) {
        this.connections = connections;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name="version")
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
@XmlRootElement(name="Connections ")
public class Connections {
    List<Connection> connection;
@XmlElement(name="Connection")  
public List<Connection> getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
    public void setConnection(List<Connection> connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
}
@XmlRootElement(name="Connection")
public class Connection {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    Share share;
@XmlAttribute(name="name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @XmlAttribute(name="description")
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
        @XmlElement(name="Share")
        public Share getShare() {
            return share;
        }
        public void setShare(Share share) {
            this.share = share;
        }
}
@XmlRootElement(name="Share")
public class Share {
private String version;
private String siteUrl;

@XmlAttribute(name="version")
public String getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="siteURL")
public String getSiteUrl() {
    return siteUrl;
}
public void setSiteUrl(String siteUrl) {
    this.siteUrl = siteUrl;
}

}
```

MAIN FILE

```
public class JAXB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        Settings ha = null;
        File fileName = new File("Config.xml");

        try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Settings.class);
         Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

          ha = (Settings)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(fileName);
        }
        catch(JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the `namespace` for the `@XmlRootElement`, but not for other elements. `@XmlElement(name="Connections")` maps the property as `Connections` element, without namespace.

Either add `namespace="urn:Adapter-v3"` to all other elements, or, better add a `package-info.java` to the package:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "urn:Adapter-v3",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.acme.foo;
```

Comment: that worked..:).If u observe my code i have an extra Connections class that comes in between Settings.class and COnnection.class.Can i avoid  this and do an implementation similar to like [XmlArray( ElementName = "Connections",IsNullable =false)]
[XmlArrayItem("Connection", typeof(Connection),  IsNullable = false)] in .net?

Comment: @user9450093 You're looking for `@XmlElementWrapper`, I guess.